# Can't get target date returned when using NSDateComponents

Tags: swift, nsdatecomponents, gregorian-calendar

I know that the following code returns the GMT time and we are currently GMT+1. I'm trying to adapt my code so the correct date is returned. If I simply add 1 hour the code it will fail when the GMT+1 reverts to GMT. Any ideas?

```
 let gregorian = NSCalendar(calendarIdentifier: NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian)!
    gregorian.timeZone = NSTimeZone.localTimeZone()
    var unitFlags : NSCalendarUnit = NSCalendarUnit.CalendarUnitYear | NSCalendarUnit.CalendarUnitWeekOfYear | NSCalendarUnit.CalendarUnitWeekday
    gregorian.firstWeekday = 2
    var components:NSDateComponents = gregorian.components(unitFlags,    fromDate: date)
    components.weekday = 2
    components.hour = 0
    components.minute = 0
    components.second = 0

    let resultDate:NSDate = gregorian.dateFromComponents(components)!

    println("The resultDate is \(resultDate)")
```

Comment: println() of an NSDate always prints the date in GMT (that does not make it "incorrect"). This looks like the same issue as in your previous question. – To print the date according to your local time zone you have to convert it back to a string with a NSDateFormatter.

Comment: Thanks Martin, I'm taking two dates and producing a pdf report of values that fall between the two dates. I know I can use NSDateFormatter to convert the dates to string values. I just can't seem to get the dates to be correct.

Answer (score 0):

I adapted my code with the following lines. I'd be grateful if anybody can spot any errors. The code does appear to work.

```
var currentZone = NSTimeZone.localTimeZone()
    if (currentZone.isDaylightSavingTimeForDate(date)) {

       components.hour = +1

    }
```